# Magento 2 Migration : Destination fields are missing

Tags: magento2, data-migration-tool

1.9.2.0 to 2.2.5 Migration i am getting bellow error any idea  how to resolve it?

```
 [2018-07-17 20:23:36][ERROR]: Destination fields are missing. Document: catalog_product_entity_decimal. Fields: row_id
    [2018-07-17 20:23:36][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: catalog_product_entity_tier_price. Fields: row_id
    [2018-07-17 20:23:36][ERROR]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: catalog_product_entity_group_price. Fields: row_id
    [2018-07-17 20:23:36][ERROR]: Destination fields are not mapped. Document: catalog_product_entity_tier_price. Fields: row_id
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
    <steps mode="settings">
        <step title="Settings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
        </step>
        <step title="Stores Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="data">
        <step title="Data Integrity Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
        </step>
        <step title="EAV Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Ratings Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Tier Price Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
            <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="PostProcessing Step">
            <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <steps mode="delta">
        <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Map Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="Log Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="OrderGrids Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
        </step>
        <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
            <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
            <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <source>
        <database host="localhost" name="m1" user="xyz" password="xyz" />
    </source>
    <destination>
        <database host="localhost" name="m2" user="xyz" password="asd" />
    </destination>
    <options>
        <map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.2.0/map.xml</map_file>
        <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
        <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
        <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
        <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
        <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
        <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
        <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
        <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
        <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
        <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
        <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
        <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
        <class_map>etc/opensource-to-commerce/class-map.xml</class_map>
        <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
        <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
        <!--
        In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
        -->
        <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
        <!--
        Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
        NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
        and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
         -->
        <direct_document_copy>0</direct_document_copy>
        <source_prefix>mg_</source_prefix>
        <dest_prefix />
        <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
        <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
        <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
        <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
        <edition_migrate>opensource-to-commerce</edition_migrate>
        <edition_number>1.9.2.0</edition_number>
        <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
        <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
        <crypt_key>jmhqfife2e5y6377k2h7jv4vvnm4cuzz</crypt_key>
    </options>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you please add your config.xml code in your question

Comment: @Rutvee Sojitra config.xml added please checked

Answer (score 1):

@Navin Bhudiya 
   please remove .xml.dist  and add .xml also convert file .xml.dist to .xml
and try

```
    <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
    <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/eav-document-groups.xml</eav_document_groups_file>
    <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/eav-attribute-groups.xml</eav_attribute_groups_file>
    <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-log.xml</log_map_file>
    <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/log-document-groups.xml</log_document_groups_file>
    <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/settings.xml</settings_map_file>
    <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-customer.xml</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/customer-document-groups.xml</customer_document_groups_file>
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/customer-attribute-groups.xml</customer_attribute_groups_file>
    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
    <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/order-grids-document-groups.xml</order_grids_document_groups_file>
    <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-document-groups.xml</map_document_groups>
    <class_map>etc/opensource-to-commerce/class-map.xml</class_map>
    <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-tier-price.xml</tier_price_map_file>
    <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-commerce/map-stores.xml</stores_map_file>
```

Comment: i did above changes still i am getting same error

Comment: @NavinBhudiya 
1) Have you changed all files extension .xml.dist to .dist?
2) Your 1.9.2.0's version and 2.2.5's version same means opensource to commerce?

Comment: Yes.................

Comment: i am migration magento 1.9.2.0 to magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Try This Command For Data Migration :-

> [-a|--auto] is an optional argument that prevents migration from
>   stopping when it encounters integrity check errors.

```
php bin/magento migrate:data --auto vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/<edition-to-edition>/<version>/config.xml
```

> "Source fields are not mapped" For This Error

**Define in vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/edition-to-edition/version/map.xml**

```
<field_rules>
      <ignore>
          <field>TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME</field>
      </ignore>
      <ignore>
          <field>catalog_product_entity_tier_price.row_id</field>
      </ignore>
      <ignore>
          <field>catalog_product_entity_group_price.row_id</field>
      </ignore>
</field_rules>
```

**And Change On Config.xml File :-**

```
<map_file>etc/edition-to-edition/version/map.xml</map_file>
```